# Combinations of activities in a fun park

Tags: combinatorics

Some friends are planning the order according to which they will visit different places in a fun park.
In this fun park there are 27 different activities, 4 restaurants and 3 coffee houses.
The friends have decided to take part in 8 of these activities, they will eat in 1 of these restaurants and they will drink coffee in 1 of these coffee houses.
We suppose that there is no limitation about the order according to which, all things above may happen.

How many different plans of visit may take place?

I am thinking of:
C(27,8)*C(4,1)*C(3,1)
Is my way of thinking right?

I would appreciate of your quidance.

Answer (score 1):

That would be the correct number of ways to choose $8$ activities, $1$ restaurant, and $1$ coffee house, but the actual number of *plans of visit* is higher since *order matters*. Specifically, those $8+1+1=10$ distinct places can be ordered in any way, so the number of plans of visit would be $$\binom{27}{8} \cdot \binom{4}{1} \cdot \binom{3}{1} \cdot 10!$$